# Request had insufficient authentication scopes - Error getting birthday from google sign-in using firebase in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-play-services, google-signin, http-status-code-403, google-people-api

I am using Flutter and I would like to get the user's birthday from google sign-in. However, I can only get the user's email, displayName but not the birthdate. I tried to add scope for getting the birthday from people API but I am getting an error. I can successfully get the user's name and email but I cannot get the birthday. Please help..

Here is the error.

```
W/.pumpit.pump_i(32752):Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe; >compareAndSwapObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z (greylist, linking, allowed)
I/flutter (32752): loading birthday
I/flutter (32752): loading completed
I/flutter (32752): api error
I/flutter (32752): {
I/flutter (32752):   "error": {
I/flutter (32752):     "code": 403,
I/flutter (32752):     "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
I/flutter (32752):     "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
I/flutter (32752):   }
I/flutter (32752): }
```

Here is my code:

```
var googleIdToken;
FirebaseUser user;

Future<FirebaseUser> signInWithGoogle() async {

final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read']
);

final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication = await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
    accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
    idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken);

googleIdToken = googleSignInAuthentication.idToken;

final AuthResult authResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
user = authResult.user;

final host = "https://people.googleapis.com";
final endpoint= "/v1/people/me/connections?personFields=names,birthdays";
final header = await googleSignInAccount.authHeaders;

print('loading birthday');
final request = await http.get("$host$endpoint", headers: header);
print('loading completed');

if(request.statusCode == 200){
  print('api working perfectly');
  print(request.body);
} else {
  print('api error');
  print(request.body);
}

// connecting to mongo database
AuthService().googleLogin(googleIdToken).then((val) {

  if (val.data['success']) {
     var token2 = val.data['token'];

     AuthService().getInfo(token2).then((val) async {
       print('SUCCESS AUTHENTICATION');
       var store = val.data['user'];

      showDialog(context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context){
            return  _SuucessLogin();
          });
      EasyLoading.dismiss();

     });
  } else {
    print('WRONG EMAIL/ PASS');
  }
});

assert(!user.isAnonymous);
assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
assert(currentUser.uid == user.uid);

return user;
```

}

Can someone help me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you get a new token after changing the scopes? @nit21

Answer (score 1):

You should use the GetPerson action to get the authenticated user, not ListConnections which is for getting contacts. See documentation https://developers.google.com/people/v1/profiles#get_the_person_for_the_authenticated_user

Comment: I'll check that. Thank you!